# Formation of MnO2 vs [Mn(H2O)6]4+ in aqueous solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

I am looking for reasons why $\ce{Mn(IV)}$ wouldn't be stable as a hydrate. I know that from standard reduction potentials it exists as a ppt of $\ce{MnO2}$, but what is stopping it from being a hydrated $\mathrm{4+}$ aqueous cation? Is it that the water ligands would be too polarised and therefore $\ce{H+}$ dissociation would occur very easily? Are there other factors that make it a solid rather than a solvated ion, like lattice enthalpy etc.?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41038/odd-acidity-trend-in-hexaaqua-metal-complexes

Answer (score 4):

Solid $\ce{MnO2}$ can be hydrated, but it's the solid which precipitates from solutions as a product of redox reactions of other $\ce{Mn}$ compounds. There is also for example crystalline $\ce{[MnF4(py)(H2O)]}$ What about aquo cations you mentioned?

One thing is that $\ce{[Mn(H2O)_n]^4+}$ cations should be indeed quite strongly acidic, but that's no problem as another strong acid in solution would prevent precipitation (similar thing like with $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$). The problem is oxidative power, what may be surprising knowing that Mn has higher oxidation states.

Why do I think so? Well, let's see what happens if we try this trick with acid to make a solution. Concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ react with $\ce{MnO2}$, but lets see the reactions:

$$\ce{2 MnO2 + 2 H2SO4 → 2 MnSO4 + O2 + 2 H2O}$$
$$\ce{MnO2 + 4 HCl → MnCl2 + Cl2 + 2 H2O}$$

In first case oxygen gets oxidised and in second chlorine!

Now what if we used $\ce{HF}$? Concentrated solutions are really powerful stuff! Unfortunately the problem persists, as you could see earlier $\ce{Mn^{4+}}$ can oxidise even water if acidity is high enough. With difficulty $\ce{MnF4}$ was synthesised, but guess what, Mn can gradually oxidise fluorine in this compound, making $\ce{F2}$ gas! That was first chemical reaction known to do that.

So, generally **not much chance for simple aquo complexes**.

Check out these articles on Wikipedia for more info and citations to articles: [about $\ce{MnF4}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese(IV)_fluoride) and [about $\ce{MnO2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese_dioxide).

Comment: >, but that's no problem as another strong acid in solution would prevent precipitation  || It's a problem because really strong acid will dissociate in water anyway, a non-water solution would be needed. Monoatomic tetracations are a very rare thing a small cations like Mn definitely are not stable enough to exist in water solution.

Comment: @permeakra Well concentrated H2SO4 is still arguably "aqueous"  Yep, I was thinking about adding a lot of acid :D