# Non existence of B3+ in solution

Tags: aqueous-solution, ions, periodic-trends, periodic-table

I read that B3+ ions do not exist in aqueous solution, because hydration energy cannot compensate for the sum of first three ionisation energies.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. If boron (III) ion really doesn't exist, how was the hydration energy data calculated? and ionisation potentials?
2. Boron being small in size and carrying a high charge of +3 (if it exists) should be greatly hydrated. This high hydration energy should be able to compensate for the ionisation energies, but it is not so.

Could someone please explain? 
Thanks!

Comment: The formation of an ordered hydration shell decreases the entropy of the system. The hydration of the ion may result in a huge decrease in entropy, which makes the overall process unfavourable.

Comment: Why should all hydration shells be ordered?

Comment: Also, if ∆S < 0, the Gibbs free energy would be negative for highly negative values of ∆H. How do we rule out or explain that possibility?

Comment: According to most chemical literature I have read, the hydration of any ion has its own associated ordered hydration shell necessarily. This is because of the attraction between the partial negative charge on the water molecule and the positive charge of the cation, in the case of positive ions. This attraction sort of fixes the position of the water molecules.

Comment: We can rule it out based on our observation that it does not exist. For these kind of thermodynamics things, we can only use data and empirical observations to substantiate.

Comment: It is observed that B3+ ions don't exist in aqueous solution, so how was it possible to calculate ∆H of a process that never happened in the first place?

Comment: Another question. According to the argument you proposed, it shouldn't be possible to hydrate any ion on basis of purely entropical factors. Clearly, that's not the case. How do we explain ∆H? I'm still not very sure

Comment: Of course. Entropy change of the system is not the only consideration. To compensate for a negative entropy change, the reaction would need to be highly exothermic, so as to ensure that the entropy of the surroundings would increase.

Comment: What are you really asking about, 'cause I think you didn't even think what you postulate or what you do not

Comment: Are you asking about something like this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74528/formation-of-mno2-vs-mnh2o64-in-aqueous-solution ?