# Why Mn atom show maximum valency of 4 with F atom?

Tags: bond, transition-metals

Mn ($3d^5$, $4s^2$) can have maximum 7 unpaired electrons in excited state so it should have formed MnF7 molecule but it can form only MnF4 molecule.

Is it because:
$d_{xy}, d_{yz}, d_{zx}$ orbitals are not axially oriented and therefore not suitable for head on sigma overlap but can form pi bonds as in Mn2O7 molecule.

Comment: Actually even MnF4 is unstable and easily decomposes to MnF3 and F2.

Comment: For some reason $\ce{MnO4-}$ with $\ce{Mn}$ at valence $+7$ is stable but there is no $\ce{MnF7}$ or $\ce{Mn^{7+}}$.

Comment: Answer could be similar as in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74528/formation-of-mno2-vs-mnh2o64-in-aqueous-solution MnF4 is already about as strong oxidant as fluorine, MnF5 would be even stronger.

Comment: @Mithoron This is surprising that MnO2 even oxidize HF to F2. But my doubt is that MnF5 is even possible? considering _ "dxy, dyz and dzx  orbitals are not axially oriented and therefore not suitable for head on sigma overlap but can form pi bonds as in Mn2O7 molecule."_

Comment: There's no problem with any orbitals, there can be even $\ce{MnF7^3-}$ anion.